# How I could regex match with string of minimum characters?

Tags: regex

for example  with this regular expression

**one.+?c**

```
onedddd c

  oned c

 onedd c
```

match only if number of character is equal or greater than 8

match this **onedddd c**

Comment: `+` is a quantifier that means "one or more". You can create specific quantifiers using numbers and curly brackets such as `{8}` which will match the preceding character or group that many times. In your case, it looks like you're already matching 3 literal characters with `one`, so you'll probably want to subtract those from your total. `one.{4}` for example will match `onedddd` but not `onedd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

```
one.{5,}c
```

What we did here is that we added `{5,}` instead of `+?` which force the code to count up until 8 characters (5 in the code plus 3 which is the number of the characters of `one`).

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IEnJu3/1